# Flies in the house daily

Tags: pest-control

almost everyday in the afternoon, there are at least 2 flies getting into the house even with the windows and doors shut. no matter how many we spray down, they always come back. any ideas to help me?

Comment: When you spray and kill the fly you see, those are the only flies you kill, and nothing happens to their source such as eggs, food source and entry ways.

Comment: I come home to flies in my house most days around the beginning of autumn when the air temperature outside starts to cool. This usually only lasts for a period of a couple of weeks though.

Comment: What sort of flies are they?

Comment: Since the question doesn't describe the flies as being atypical, I'll assume it refers to regular largish houseflies.  However, if they are fairly small, they could be drain flies, which keep reappearing because they are already living inside the house, in a sink drain or similar place.  If that's the case, here's a link about them and how to get rid of them: https://www.doyourownpestcontrol.com/drainflies.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed any unusual odors, I'm referring to a possible dead animal. If you have a fireplace open the damper and check for odors. If you have a crawl space under your home check there also. Another source may be your attic.